# Is posible accept all kind of resources in Restful Jersey web service?

Tags: java, rest, jersey-2.0

Is there any way to accept and handle any resource, i.e.

I want to handle `myappname/xxx` where `xxx` could be anything, and how could I handle?

Note: I already know is posible create any class and then bind a resource to a class, but I don't want it. I want a one universal class that handles every resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Jersey well, but as it implements JAX-RS I expexted that would work (not tested):

```
@Path("/myappname")
public class CatchItAll {

    @GET
    @Path("/{anyThing:.*}")
    public String catch(@PathParam("anyThing") String anyThing) {

    }
}
```

It uses the regular expression feature.

Comment: I get it! Just need to add the following line @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)